# Scrollbar doesn't appear when scrolling

Tags: javafx

I'm using HiddenSidesPane to show and hide scrollbar when needed. Scrollbar appears when I move mouse to the edge of the ScrollPane and hides when I move back. However, I have a problem to show scrollbar when the scrolling is detected. You can find my code below:

FXML:

```
    <?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import org.controlsfx.control.HiddenSidesPane?>
<?import java.net.URL?>
<ScrollPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="hypermap.components.featurespanel.view.properties.PropertiesTab" fx:id="propertyTabRoot"
            fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" vbarPolicy="NEVER">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@Scrollbar.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <HiddenSidesPane fx:id="hiddenSidesPane" minWidth="280">
        <content>
            <VBox fx:id="vboxInsideScroll">
                <VBox fx:id="groupsContainer"/>
                <VBox fx:id="messageContainer"/>
            </VBox>
        </content>
    </HiddenSidesPane>
</ScrollPane>
```

CSS file:

```
.scroll-pane{
    -fx-focus-color: none;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;

}

.scroll-bar > .increment-button, .decrement-button, .increment-arrow, .decrement-arrow{
    -fx-pref-height: 0;
}

.scroll-bar:vertical{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-pref-width: 10;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb{
    -fx-background-color: color-dark-slate;
    -fx-border-radius: 100;
    -fx-padding: 0 4 0 0;
    -fx-opacity: 0.2
}

.scroll-bar:vertical .track{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Controller file with method using HiddenSidesPane:

```
@FXML
private VBox groupsContainer;

@FXML
private VBox messageContainer;

@FXML
private ScrollPane propertyTabRoot;

@FXML
private HiddenSidesPane hiddenSidesPane;

private void makeScrollable(ScrollPane scrollPane) {
        final Node scrollbar = scrollPane.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");


        hiddenSidesPane.setRight(scrollbar);
        hiddenSidesPane.setTriggerDistance(40);
        hiddenSidesPane.setAnimationDuration(Duration.millis(500));

        scrollPane.setOnScroll((event -> {
            hiddenSidesPane.setRight(scrollbar);
            event.consume();
        }));
```

I would be very grateful for any help. Also, I don't know why the scrollbar's thumb has the same hight all the time, even if the content is so huge that it should be smaller.
Thank you!

Comment: scrollPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, event -> hiddenSidesPane.setPinnedSide(Side.RIGHT));
        scrollPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> hiddenSidesPane.setPinnedSide(null));

Comment: But still I don't know how to change the height of the scrollbar's thumb. Any help?